# See what reaches my WeakObject

Tags: java, reference

I am coding a plugin for server which generates a layer for "player" in which plugin stores some of my data. Everything is saved in weak variables - WeakReference, WeakHashMap, etc.

For some reason when player logs out and server-player is pwned by GC, my layer is not.

How can I see what thread/object/anything reaches/uses my layer-object? Any premade methods for it?

There is also option to pawn it on my own - would 'player-layer = null;' after player logs out be fine?

Comment: You can use external tools like `JProfiler` (not free) to see what object is still keeping a reference to your layer. If you want to write an automated test, I would suggest [`NBTestCase#assertGC`](http://bits.netbeans.org/dev/javadoc/org-netbeans-modules-nbjunit/org/netbeans/junit/NbTestCase.html) which will print out the same information

Comment: If you have access to the server VM you may want to have a look at [Browsing a Heap Dump](http://visualvm.java.net/heapdump.html) with JVisualVM.